# generator button and check button for happy numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a program that has 2 buttons:

1. generator button which, when pressed, **generates 10 random numbers.**
2. the check button that is **only activated after the generator button** is pressed and when the random numbers are displayed, **the check button displays the 3 happy numbers** among those generated numbers. **the generator button works perfectly but the check button denied for me**.

```js
function winning(number) {
    var m, digit ;
    var cycle = [] ;
 
    while(number != 1 && cycle[number] !== true) {
        cycle[number] = true ;
        m = 0 ;
        while (number > 0) {
            digit = number % 10 ;
            m += digit * digit ;
            number = (number  - digit) / 10 ;
        }
        number = m ;
    }
    return (number == 1) ;
}
 
var cnt = 3;
var x = 1 ;
 var y = '';
while(cnt-- > 0) {
    while(!winning(x))
        x++ ;
   y=y+(x + " ,") ;
    x++ ;
}


function generator(size, lowest, highest) {
 var numbers = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * highest) + 1;
   numbers.push(randomNumber);
    
  }
  
 document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = numbers.join(" - ");
 
}
```

```html
<main>
<h1> Lottery Number Generator</h1>
<div class="submit">
  <button onclick="generator(10, 1, 50);">Generate</button>
</div>
<div id="bar"></div>

<button onclick="winning()">check</button>
<div id="bark"></div>
  </main>
```

Comment: You are calling `winning` without a param when the check button is clicked. the `while(cnt-- > 0) {` is called immediately your page loads before the generator button is clicked, that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the `check` button with CSS until you can show it. Now, for generating the lucky numbers, you can select a random index from your `numbers[]`.

Note, each time you select a lucky number, it must be removed from the array to make sure you generate unique lucky numbers.

```js
var numbers = [];

function generator(size, lowest, highest) {
  numbers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * highest) + 1;
    numbers.push(randomNumber);
  }
  document.getElementById("check").classList.remove('hide');
  document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = numbers.join(" - ");

}

function check() {
  let tmp_arr = [...numbers],
    lucky = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let idx = getIndex(tmp_arr);
    lucky.push(tmp_arr[idx]);
    tmp_arr.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  console.log(`Lucky Numbers - ${lucky.join(' - ')}`);
}

function getIndex(arr) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1> Lottery Number Generator</h1>
  <div class="submit">
    <button onclick="generator(10, 1, 50);">Generate</button>
  </div>
  <div id="bar"></div>

  <button onclick="check()" class="hide" id="check">check</button>
  <div id="bark"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: yeah, man, thanks.now i knwo where i made mistakes. i'm still a very cheap programmer, i see. thank u very much.

happy day

Comment: ,eve if it works, but there i something that i didn't understand well: why would  put " 1" in  splice method?

on this line:tmp_arr.splice(idx, 1); why that number 1? why are us removing 1 from idx?

Comment: that's the splice method for the array, which requires you to pass a start and count, which in turn would delete elements from the `start` index until the count is reached. [Refer this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)